# Non standard evaluation from another function in R

Tags: r

Here is an example from Hadley's advanced R book:

```
sample_df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:1, c = c(5, 3, 1, 4, 1))

subset2 <- function(x, condition) {
  condition_call <- substitute(condition)
  r <- eval(condition_call, x, parent.frame())
  x[r, ]
}

scramble <- function(x) x[sample(nrow(x)), ]

subscramble <- function(x, condition) {
  scramble(subset2(x, condition))
}

subscramble(sample_df, a >= 4)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

Hadley explains:

> Can you see what the problem is? condition_call contains the expression condition. So when we evaluate condition_call it also evaluates condition, which has the value a >= 4. However, this can’t be computed because there’s no object called a in the parent environment.

I understand that there is no `a` in the parent env, but, `eval(condition_call, x, parent.frame())` evals conditional_call in x (a data.frame used as an environment), enclosed by `parent.frame()`. As long as there is a column named `a` in x, why should there be any problem?

Answer (score 16):

## tl;dr

When `subset2()` is called from within `subscramble()`,
`condition_call`'s value is the symbol `condition` (rather than the
call `a >= 4` that results when it is called directly). `subset()`'s
call to `eval()` searches for `condition` first in `envir=x` (the
data.frame `sample_df`). Not finding it there, it next searches in `enclos=parent.frame()` where it *does* find an object named
`condition`.

That object is a promise object, whose expression slot is
`a >= 4` and whose evaluation environment is `.GlobalEnv`. Unless an
object named `a` is found in `.GlobalEnv` or further up the search
path, evaluation of the promise then fails with the observed message
that: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found`.

---

## Detailed explanation

A nice way to discover what's going wrong here is to insert a
`browser()` call right before the line at which `subset2()`
fails. That way, we can call it both directly and indirectly (from
within another function), and examine why it succeeds in the first case and
fails in the second.

```
subset2 <- function(x, condition) {
  condition_call <- substitute(condition)
  browser()
  r <- eval(condition_call, x, parent.frame())  ## <- Point of failure
  x[r, ]
}
```

---

#### Calling subset2() directly

When a user calls `subset2()` directly,
`condition_call <- substitute(condition)` assigns to `condition_call` a "call" object
containing the unevaluated call `a >= 4`. This call is passed in to
`eval(expr, envir, enclos)`, which needs as its first argument a
symbol that evaluates to an object of class `call`, `name`, or
`expression`. So far so good.

```
subset2(sample_df, a >= 4)
## Called from: subset2(sample_df, a >= 4)
Browse[1]> is(condition_call)
## [1] "call"     "language"
Browse[1]> condition_call
## a >= 4
```

`eval()` now sets to work, searching for the values of any symbols
contained in `expr=condition_call` first in `envir=x` and then (if
needed) in `enclos=parent.frame()` and its enclosing environments. In
this case, it finds the symbol `a` in `envir=x` (and the symbol `>=`
in `package:base`) and successfully completes the evaluation.

```
Browse[1]> ls(x)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
Browse[1]> get("a", x)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
Browse[1]> eval(condition_call, x, parent.frame())
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

#### Calling subset2() from within subscramble()

Within the body of `subscramble()`, `subset2()` is called like this:
`subset2(x, condition)`. Fleshed out, that call is really equivalent
to `subset2(x=x, condition=condition)`. Because its **supplied**
argument (i.e. the value passed to the **formal** argument named
`condition`) is the expression `condition`,
`condition_call <- substitute(condition)` assigns to `condition_call` the symbol object `condition`. (Understanding that point is pretty key to understanding exactly how the nested call fails.)

Since `eval()` is happy to have a symbol (aka "name") as its first
argument, once again so far so good.

```
subscramble(sample_df, a >= 4)
## Called from: subset2(x, condition)
Browse[1]> is(condition_call)
## [1] "name"      "language"  "refObject"
Browse[1]> condition_call
## condition
```

Now `eval()` goes to work searching for the unresolved symbol
`condition`. No column in `envir=x` (the data.frame `sample_df`)
matches, so it moves on to `enclos=parent.frame()` For fairly
complicated reasons, that environment turns out to be the evaluation
frame of the call to `subscramble()`. There, it **does** find
an object named `condition`.

```
Browse[1]> ls(x)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
Browse[1]> ls(parent.frame()) ## Aha! Here's an object named "condition"
## [1] "condition" "x"
```

As an important aside, it turns out there are several objects named `condition` on the call stack above the environment from which `browser()` was called.

```
Browse[1]> sys.calls()
# [[1]]
# subscramble(sample_df, a >= 4)
# 
# [[2]]
# scramble(subset2(x, condition))
# 
# [[3]]
# subset2(x, condition)               
# 
Browse[1]> sys.frames()
# [[1]]
# <environment: 0x0000000007166f28>   ## <- Envt in which `condition` is evaluated
# 
# [[2]]
# <environment: 0x0000000007167078>
# 
# [[3]]
# <environment: 0x0000000007166348>   ## <- Current environment


## Orient ourselves a bit more
Browse[1]> environment()            
# <environment: 0x0000000007166348>
Browse[1]> parent.frame()           
# <environment: 0x0000000007166f28>

## Both environments contain objects named 'condition'
Browse[1]> ls(environment())
# [1] "condition"      "condition_call" "x"             
Browse[1]> ls(parent.frame())
# [1] "condition" "x"
```

To inspect the `condition` object found by `eval()` (the one in `parent.frame()`, which turns out to be the evaluation frame of `subscramble()`) takes some special care. I used `recover()`
and `pryr::promise_info()` as shown below.

That inspection reveals that `condition` is a promise whose expression slot is `a >= 4` and whose
environment is `.GlobalEnv`. Our search for `a` has by this point moved well
past `sample_df` (where a value of `a` was to be found), so evaluation of the
expression slot fails (unless an object named `a` is found in `.GlobalEnv` or
somewhere else farther up the search path).

```
Browse[1]> library(pryr) ## For is_promise() and promise_info()  
Browse[1]> recover()
# 
# Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
# 
# 1: subscramble(sample_df, a >= 4)
# 2: #2: scramble(subset2(x, condition))
# 3: #1: subset2(x, condition)
# 
Selection: 1
# Called from: top level 
Browse[3]> is_promise(condition)
# [1] TRUE
Browse[3]> promise_info(condition)
# $code
# a >= 4
# 
# $env
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# 
# $evaled
# [1] FALSE
# 
# $value
# NULL
# 
Browse[3]> get("a", .GlobalEnv)
# Error in get("a", .GlobalEnv) : object 'a' not found
```

---

For one more piece of evidence that the promise object `condition` is being found
in `enclos=parent.frame()`, one can point `enclos` somewhere else farther up
the search path, so that `parent.frame()` is skipped during `condition_call`'s evaluation. When one does
that, `subscramble()` again fails, but this time with a message that
`condition` itself was not found.

```
## Compare
Browse[1]> eval(condition_call, x, parent.frame())
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from #4) : object 'a' not found

Browse[1]> eval(condition_call, x, .GlobalEnv)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from #4) : object 'condition' not found
```

Comment: Nice to get the clarification on the eval behavior that triggers this, and the use of browser().

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Excellent piece of research in both answers (and thank you) but exploring this myself, I fell  onto a wall trying to apply the above explanation. Being in the browser (same place as yours) the following command: `eval(condition_call, x, parent.env(environment()))` returns: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'condition' not found`. If the explanation that the promise is evaluated first in the `subscramble(sample_df, a >= 4) ` call where `condition` exists then I shouldn't be receiving this error, right? I should be receiving `object 'a' not found`.

Comment: @LyzandeR You're right. That's fascinating. So now, what it (strongly) looks like to me is that `condition_call`'s value really is treated as a symbol named `condition`. It is first searched for in `envir=sample_data` where, of course, it's not found. Next it's searched for in `enclos=parent.frame()` where a promise object of that name **does** exist, with value `a>=4`. But since the symbol `a` doesn't exist in `enclos`, nor in its parent environment (`.GlobalEnv`) or anywhere else further up the search path, it throws the error we see.

Comment: @LyzandeR In your nifty example, with `enclos=parent.env(environment())`, the symbol table in `parent.frame()` (where the promise named `condition` is stored) is bypassed during the lookup process, so we get an error that `object 'condition' not found`. Super interesting, and it actually makes more sense than my explanation, which had to ignore the fact that `is(condition_call)` was flat out telling me that its values was a `name`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those last two comments give the real answer. No time to write it up right now, though.  Do you think I should eventually write it up as a separate answer, or rewrite this one?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks Josh! This is amazing! I felt inside of me that the initial explanation was missing something but now I am very confident that this is the right answer. Finally!! I have been thinking about this question for the last 2 days. This sounds like the right explanation and all of the pieces seem to be connecting (without violating any internal R rules that I know of).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I think you should rewrite this one, but please try to be as explanatory as in this answer (because the process of finding the answer above is perfect - shows a methodology of how to solve a problem which is equally as important). Also, please try to keep the process of finding the answer (i.e. keep the browser parts as well as the last bit of code using `is_promise` and `sys.frames` and `sys.calls`) as I found it extremely helpful. Thanks again for this. Really good research, good R knowledge and a very good explanation all in all. Thanks.

Comment: @LyzandeR Yes, those are *exactly* the feelings I had and now have. The explanation I gave yesterday made me think, is that *really* how they've set things up? Can that be? How annoying! I'll go ahead and rewrite this, but possibly not until tomorrow. And I will certainly leave the intermediate steps in there. I think I included that in the first place because I wanted to show my not-fully baked thought process, and I'm glad I did; tracking this one down with you and Sean Murphy has been a very rewarding pursuit.

Comment: Indeed it has for me as well, I learnt a lot :) and I am 100% certain that many users will find it extremely helpful too. Well done!

Comment: @LyzandeR OK, I just posted a completely rewritten (and now correct!) answer. The explanation's not real polished, but I think it basically captures what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

This was a tricky one, so thanks for the question. The error has to do with how substitute acts when it's called on an argument. If we look at the help text from substitute():

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. **If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol.**

What this means is that when you evaluate `condition` within the nested subset2 function, `substitute` sets `condition_call` to be the promise object of the unevaluated 'condition' argument. Since promise objects are pretty obscure, the definition is here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects

The key points from there are:

> Promise objects are part of R’s lazy evaluation mechanism. They contain three slots: a value, an expression, and an environment.

and

> When the argument is accessed, the stored expression is evaluated in the stored environment, and the result is returned

Basically, within the nested function, `condition_call` is set to the promise object `condition`, rather than the substitution of the actual expression contained within `condition`. Because promise objects 'remember' the environment they come from, it seems this overrides the behavior of `eval()` - so regardless of the second argument to eval(), `condition_call` is evaluated within the parent environment that the argument was passed from, in which there is no 'a'.

You can create promise objects with `delayedAssign()` and observe this directly:

```
delayedAssign("condition", a >= 4)
substitute(condition)
eval(substitute(condition), sample_df)
```

You can see that `substitute(condition)` does not return `a >= 4`, but simply `condition`, and that trying to evaluate it within the environment of `sample_df` fails as it does in Hadley's example.

Hopefully this is helpful, and I'm sure someone else can clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this thread, here is the answer to task #5 below this section in Hadley's book. It also contains a possible general solution to the problem discussed above.

```
subset2 <- function(x, condition, env = parent.frame()) {
  condition_call <- substitute(condition, env)
  r <- eval(condition_call, x, env)
  x[r, ]
}
scramble <- function(x) x[sample(nrow(x)), ]
subscramble <- function(x, condition) {
  scramble(subset2(x, condition))
}
subscramble(sample_df, a >= 3)
```

The magic happens in the second line of `subset2`. There, `substitute` receives an explicite `env` argument. From the help section for `substitute`: "`substitute` returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression `expr`, substituting any variables bound in `env`." `env` "Defaults to the current evaluation environment". Instead, we use the calling environment.

Check it out like this:

```
debugonce(subset2)
subscramble(sample_df, a >= 3)
Browse[2]> substitute(condition)
condition
Browse[2]> substitute(condition, env)
a >= 3
```

I am not 100% certain about the explanation here. I think it just is the way `substitute` works. From the help page for `substitute`:

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree
>   as follows: (...) If it is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument
>   to a function or explicitly created using `delayedAssign()`, the
>   expression slot of the promise replaces the symbol. If it is an
>   ordinary variable, its value is substituted (...).

In the current environment, `condition` is a promise, so the expression slot is filled, and more importantly, condition_call receives a symbol as a value. In the calling environment, `condition` is just an ordinary variable, so the value (the expression) is substituted.